# assigning node value to variable based on presence or absence of node in xslt

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to assign the  value of one variable  to another variable based on if a node is present in XML or else value of another node would be assigned.I know the Xpaths of both the nodes .Please find part of the XSL code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="partMetaOriginal" select="book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type='chapter']/book-part-meta"/>  
<xsl:variable name="person" select="book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type='part']/body/book-part[@book-part-type='chapter']/book-part-meta"/> 
<xsl:variable name="partMeta"> 
    <xsl:if test="book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type='part']">
       <xsl:value-of select="$person"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

while using value of the variable '**partMeta**' in rest of my xsl, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
           :Error checking type of the expression 'FilterParentPath(variable-ref(partMeta/result-tree), step("child", 48))'.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:865)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:649)
    at com.molcon.xmlToXSLT.XMLTransform.main(XMLTransform.java:21)
Caused by: Error checking type of the expression 'FilterParentPath(variable-ref(partMeta/result-tree), step("child", 48))'.
```

Java version - 1.6

PS:I need a code which can assign appropriate node value to my variable partMeta , based on condition which is nothing but the value of the attribute '**book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type]**'.So if the value is 'chapter', the variable gets the value of variable 'partMetaOriginal' else it gets the value of variable 'person' .This variable is used to navigate to other child nodes.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve with `for-each select="$partMeta"`, you have created a variable with some text contents with the `xsl:value-of`, so selecting anything with a `for-each` wouldn't make any sense even in XSLT 2 or 3 where you can use XPath on variable with node contents. But in XSLT 1, even if you used `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`, you have a result tree fragment you can't use XPath on. Perhaps just use `<xsl:variable name="partMeta" select="book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type='part']/body/book-part[@book-part-type='chapter']/book-part-meta"/>`.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], not fragments taken out of context.

Comment: Hi michael .appologies for the unclear question.I Have edited the query and limited it to the part i have problem In.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you understand what a [mcve] is.

Comment: @michael.hor257k an answer pertaining to the given problem would be appreciated .Else thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work, not sure if that's what you really want. Also, if you want to test attribute book-part-type, the correct xpath would be book-part-wrapper/book-part/@book-part-type. You just need to change it on the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="partMetaOriginal" select="book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type='chapter']/book-part-meta"/>  
    <xsl:variable name="person" select="book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type='part']/body/book-part[@book-part-type='chapter']/book-part-meta"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="partMeta">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="book-part-wrapper/book-part[@book-part-type] = 'chapter'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$partMetaOriginal"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$person"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```